# Geodesics on subsets of manifolds defined by a Euclidean coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

In the course of my research, I'm trying to prove properties about geodesics using the canonical Euclidean metric for a certain class of manifolds called "aligned manifolds".  First, I'll describe aligned manifolds and then state the main question that I have.

## Aligned Manifolds

First, let $E$ be an $n$-dimensional Euclidean coordinate system.  Let $v = (v^1,v^2,...,v^n)$ be an $n$-dimensional vector in $E$.  We define the **sign** of $v$ as:

$$sign(v) = (sign(v^1),sign(v^2),...,sign(v^n))$$

where the $sign$ of a scalar is 1, 0, or -1 if the scalar is positive, zero, or negative respectively.

A connected manifold $M$ is **aligned** with respect to $E$ if:

$$\forall x,y\in M\ldotp \forall v_x\in T_xM\ldotp \exists x_y\in T_yM\ldotp sign(v_x)=sign(v_y)$$

In other words, for every pair of points $x$ and $y$ in $M$ and every vector in the tangent space at $x$, there exists a vector in the tangent space at $y$ that points in the same overall direction.  In 2 dimension, both tangent vectors point to the same quadrant; in 3 dimesions, both point to the same octant, etc.  One can define aligned manifolds using the co-tangent space instead of the tangent space to describe the same set of manifolds.

**Examples**: 
In $\mathbb{R}^2$: The open arc of a circle from 0 degrees to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ degrees is aligned.
The arc of a circle from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ degrees to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ degrees is not aligned.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$: A manifold defined as $\{x^2+y^2=1,x>0,y<0,z>x+y^2\}$ is aligned.
A hemi-sphere of a 2-sphere is not aligned.

## Main Question

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition.** Let $M$ be an aligned manifold.  For any pair of points $x,y\in M$, there exists at most one geodesic $\gamma: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$, $\gamma(1)=y$, and $\forall t\in[0,1]\ldotp \gamma(t)\in M$.

This is equivalent to asking if there do not exist any conjugate points in $M$.  I've been trying to tackle this problem by showing that a Jacobi field which vanishes in $M$ cannot exist, although I haven't had much luck.  The Cartan theorem gives us geodesic completeness if sectional curvature is non-positive;  however, aligned manifolds may have positive curvature.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions of how to go about proving this proposition or alternatively, a counter-example that demonstrates that the proposition is false.

Comment: Just a comment, I think saying "M is aligned **with respect to $E$**" is misleading as $E$ plays no role in the definition of being aligned.

Comment: The Euclidean coordinate system plays the role of defining the tangent space, specifically the signs of vectors in the tangent space.  Therefore, a manifold that is aligned relative to one Euclidean coordinate system.

Comment: For example, under the standard Euclidean coordinate system, the manifold defined as the arc of a circle from $\frac{\pi}{8}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{8}$ is aligned.  However, under a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ rotated coordinate system spanned by the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$, that manifold would not be aligned as the tangent vector at $\frac{\pi}{8}$ would be negative w.r.t. $(1,1)$ and the tangent vector at $\frac{3\pi}{8}$ would be positive w.r.t. $(1,1)$.